# c++ Call function before logout

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to execute a function on user logout, but the program close before function call, is there any way to wait function finish the function execution?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>  
using namespace std;
bool done = false;

void createFile() {
    ofstream outfile("test.txt");
    outfile << "test" << std::endl;
    outfile.close();
}

BOOL WINAPI consoleHandler(DWORD signal) {
    switch (signal)
    {
    case CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT:
        printf("Logoff");
        done = true;
        Sleep(20000); // force exit after 20 seconds
        return TRUE;
    case CTRL_C_EVENT:
        printf("Ctrl+c");
        done = true;
        Sleep(20000); // force exit after 20 seconds
        return TRUE;

    case CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:
        printf("close");
        done = true;
        Sleep(20000); // force exit after 20 seconds
        return TRUE;

    default:
        // Pass signal on to the next handler
        return FALSE;
    }
}


int main()
{
    if (!SetConsoleCtrlHandler(consoleHandler, TRUE)) {
        printf("\nERROR: Could not set control handler");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Runing");
    while (!done) {
        printf(".");
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    createFile(); //Dont called on user logout but called on close and ctrl+c
    printf("\nEnding\n");
    Sleep(1000);
    return 0;
}
```

> On **CTRL_C_EVENT** and **CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT**

The file **test.txt** is created but on

> **CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT**

The program close instantly, without call the function.

Comment: "Note that this signal is received only by services" says [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/handlerroutine).

Comment: I recommend reviewing your language tags.  The C language doesn't have the `fstream` header.  You will be less confused if you pick a single language.

Answer (score 0):

Since my answer has been down voted, I guess I need to be more pedantic.

first of all, since you are not getting the CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT you may want to consult the this doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler).  The critical section being:

```
If a console application loads the gdi32.dll or user32.dll library, the 
HandlerRoutine function that you specify when you call SetConsoleCtrlHandler 
does not get called for the CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT and CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT events. The 
operating system recognizes processes that load gdi32.dll or user32.dll as Windows 
applications rather than console applications. This behavior also occurs for 
console applications that do not call functions in gdi32.dll or user32.dll 
directly, but do call functions such as Shell functions that do in turn call 
functions in gdi32.dll or user32.dll.

To receive events when a user signs out or the device shuts down in these 
circumstances, create a hidden window in your console application, and then handle 
the WM_QUERYENDSESSION and WM_ENDSESSION window messages that the hidden window 
receives. You can create a hidden window by calling the CreateWindowEx method with 
the dwExStyle parameter set to 0.
```

You might also want to read ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376890(v=vs.85).aspx ).

Now, what I had previously suggested is to use the SetWindowsHookEx which should work as all windows messages pass through it (it is what Spy uses to view the message queues  (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2007/01/16/spy-internals/)). 20 years ago, you would have to do something like this for certain messages that were not passed through to your window - as in your case where the windows message is processed up stream of the current window.  You may come across old code that does this, or there may be situations that you still need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me apologise : I'll not answer the specific 'CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT' you are referring, but the generic feature you're trying to accomplish : 'execute a function on user logout'.

**A generic way to do:**

As far as I know, there is no generic way to do.

You may try various solutions :

- catching events as you did
- using try catch / finally
- spawn windows timers and react to it
- spawn threads that will wait for the main thread to end

But (as far as I know) all of them have a weakness to a way to close or another.

For instance, I recently had to struggle with a poorly coded dll I had to use. This dll was calling "exit(0)". I found no elegant way to gracefully handle this behaviour.

I had to launch it in a separated process (not thread), that I was monitoring from my main process. It's a lot of work to implement and to maintain for a simple result.

**Another approach:**

Depending on what you are trying to do, it may be a good practice to make your "final" operation gradually, using a format that allows you to recover partially written files.

It's what I would generally do, but it always depends on what you are trying to achieve.

For instance, if you're trying to clean your workspace, you may want to:

- do it at start in the case it was not done in the previous run
- work in temporary folders

Another case, if you have a very long process and want to generate summary file, you may want to:

- generate a partial summary file from time to time
- as you generate a new file, you move the previous one

that way, you'll have a partial summary file at every step of your process.